# Is YQL (Yahoo Query Language) still supported?

Tags: web-crawler, yahoo, yql, yahoo-pipes

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Id like to use YQL for a project, but:

- All of the resources seem about 5 years old.
- About 50% of the examples on the homepage are broken.
- Some of the links do not work (Forums).

According to [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/2ig906/alternative_to_yql/) post, YQL permissions change often and the service is unpredictable.

Is the project still active, is it ok to use for a production system?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't invest too much resources into anything from Yahoo, given their various issues, especially if the latest blog post is from three years ago. It may not be formally deprecated, but those are never great signs.

Answer (score 1):

it is not still supported,  I just asked one of my co-workers who used to be a developer at Yahoo and he said it was no longer supported

Comment: I'd like to see actual evidence for this. There's no deprecation message on the YQL blog, nor the website, nor the documentation, nor does https://www.google.com/search?q=yql+deprecated turn anything much up.